# SwiftUI - Spell Checking Multi-line String

Tags: swift, swiftui, uitextchecker

I am trying to create a function where a multi-line string is spell checked and a single SwiftUI Text() view is returned with any misspelled words highlighted in red.

I have almost cracked it by splitting the string by newlines, then splitting the lines by whitespace and then checking each word.

My main issue is that I am getting an extra new line added at the end of the resulting Text view. Is there anyway I can trim the last `Text("\n")` or prevent it from being added to the last line?

Also, if there is any way to make it more efficient as there is a slight lag introduced as a lot of text in an array gets checked and so the function is called many times?

Many thanks in advance

```
func formatText(multiLineText: String) -> Text {
    
    let lineArray = multiLineText.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    let stringToTextView = lineArray.reduce(Text(""), {
        return $0 + formatLineText(singleLineText: $1) + Text("\n")
    })
    return stringToTextView
}

func formatLineText(singleLineText: String) -> Text {
    
    let stringArray = singleLineText.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
    let stringToTextView = stringArray.reduce(Text(""), {
        if !wordIsValid(word: $1) {
            return $0 + Text($1).foregroundColor(Color.red).underline() + Text(" ")
        }
        else {
            return $0 + Text($1) + Text(" ")
        }
    })
    return stringToTextView
}

func wordIsValid(word: String) -> Bool {
    
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_GB")

    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.enumerated` in your `reduce` to check to see if the item is the last one or not -- if it is, don't return the `\n`.

```
func formatText(multiLineText: String) -> Text {
    let lineArray = multiLineText.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    let stringToTextView = lineArray.enumerated().reduce(Text(""), { (acc,item) in
        return acc + formatLineText(singleLineText: item.1) + Text(item.0 != lineArray.endIndex - 1 ? "\n" : "")
    })
    return stringToTextView
}
```

In terms of performance, I'd move the `let checker = UITextChecker()` to somewhere where it doesn't get recreated on every single call to `wordIsValid`